# Parquet Format - split columns in different files

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, parquet

On the parquet documentation is explicitly mentioned that the design supports splitting the metadata and data into different files , including also the possibility that different column groups can be stored in different files.

However , I could not find any instructions on how to achieve that. In my use case I would like to store the metadata in one file , store columns 1-100 data in one file and 101-200 in a second file .

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Hello did you find any resources related to your problem?